# How to Get process info using Powershell into a SQL Server table with each property in a different row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

In T-SQL, I have been able to run a powershell command get-process and get the resultant data I am looking for except that when it comes into the table, all the properties come into a single column for each process.

How can I get the properties to break out into separate columns?

This sample code pulls the username and the Path:

```
create table #output (id int identity(1,1), output nvarchar(255) null)
insert #output (output) Exec xp_cmdshell 'powershell.exe Invoke-Command -ComputerName 
MyServer -ScriptBlock {Get-Process -IncludeUserName ^| select username,path} ^| select * -exclude PSComputerName,RunspaceID ^| Format-Table -AutoSize'
select * from #output 
drop table #output
```

How can I get the username and path in separate columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write your code like this. You will have to tweak this pseudo code a bit.

```
$resultSet = Get-Process -IncludeUserName | select username,path | select * -exclude PSComputerName,RunspaceID 

" Create Table outputData (UserName varchar(50), Path varchar (1000) )"
$out-null = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $store  -query $sql   -ConnectionTimeout 60 -QueryTimeout 10000


foreach ($i in $resultSet) {
$userName = $i.UserName
$path = $i.path 

" insert outputData values ('$UserName','$path') "
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $store  -query $sql   -ConnectionTimeout 60 -QueryTimeout 10000
}
```